# PyTorch: Calculating the Hessian vector product with nn.parameters()

Tags: pytorch

Using PyTorch, I would like to calculate the Hessian vector product, where the Hessian is the second-derivative matrix of the loss function of some neural net, and the vector will be the vector of gradients of that loss function.

I know how to calculate the Hessian vector product for a regular function thanks to [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/calculating-hessian-vector-product/11240/3). However, I am running into trouble when the function is the loss function of a neural network. This is because the parameters are packaged into a module, accessible via nn.parameters(), and not a torch tensor.

I want to do something like this (doesn't work):

```
### a simple neural network 
linear = nn.Linear(10, 20) 

x = torch.randn(1, 10) 

y = linear(x).sum()
### compute the gradient and make a copy that is detached from the graph 
grad = torch.autograd.grad(y, linear.parameters(),create_graph=True)

v = grad.clone().detach()
### compute the Hessian vector product 
z = grad @ v 
z.backward()
```

In analogy this this (does work):

```
x = Variable(torch.Tensor([1, 1]), requires_grad=True)

f = 3*x[0]**2 + 4*x[0]*x[1] + x[1]**2

grad, = torch.autograd.grad(f, x, create_graph=True)

v = grad.clone().detach()

z = grad @ v

z.backward()
```

[This post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cannot-compute-hessian-vector-product-of-nn-module/19815) addresses a similar (possibly the same?) issue, but I don't understand the solution.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to calculate the hessian for each set of weights in the network? In this case your model has two sets of weights: the weight matrix `w` and a bias vector `b`.

Comment: Correct - I would like to be able take derivatives wtf to the unrolled vector of the parameters in w and b (call it Theta).

Answer (score 0):

You are saying `it doesn't work` but do not show what error you get, this is why you haven't got any answers

`torch.autograd.grad(outputs, inputs, grad_outputs=None, retain_graph=None, create_graph=False, only_inputs=True, allow_unused=False)`

> outputs and inputs are expected to be sequences of tensors. But you
>   use just a tensor as outputs.

What this is saying is that you should pass a sequence, so pass `[y]` instead of `y`